# Does Quartz.NET trigger a misfire if the Windows service was stopped?

Tags: scheduling, quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz.NET dll with AdoJobStore inside a Windows service. I noticed that the tutorial isn't very clear about misfires.

The question: Is a misfire supposed to be triggered if the Windows service was stopped when the job should have been executed? The Quartz.NET tutorial says: "A misfire occurs if a persistent trigger "misses" its firing time because of the scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no available threads in Quartz's thread pool for executing the job". So does that mean that if the service itself is stopped no misfire is triggered (because that's what happens to me)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. The misfire will happen whenever the scheduler is started up again. In essence the misfire happens when the scheduler checks when a job should run and it determines that the fire time for the job is in the past.